# Запись строк массива по файлам

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется массив строк.
Пользователь вводит число строк для разбиения и создаются файлы. Например массив состоит из 5000 строк, пользователь ввел 1000, создаются 5 файлов и туда записываются строки. Как это можно реализовать?
Я начал, но не совсем понимаю как закончить

```
    $number = count($arr); //5000
    $v = 1000;
    $res= $number / $v;

    for($i = 1; $i <= $res; $i++ )
    {
        $fp = fopen($dir_e.'/file_'.$i.'.txt', "w"); 
        $r = $i * $res;
//тут нужно еще раз циклом пройтись
        fwrite($fp, "");
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

Подскажите как правильно это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$v = 1000; // число, которое ввел юзер

foreach(array_chunk($arr, $v) as $index => $chunk) {
    $fp = fopen($dir_e.'/file_'.$index.'.txt', "w");

    foreach($chunk as $str) {
        fwrite($fp, $str);
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с использованием одного цикла:

```
$number = count($arr); //5000
$v = 1000;
for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
    if ($i % $v === 0) {
        if (isset($fp)) fclose($fp);
        $fp = fopen($dir_e.'/file_' . floor($i / $v ) . '.txt', "wb+");
    }
    fwrite($fp, $arr[$i]);
}
if (isset($fp)) fclose($fp);
```